# Using Firebase noSouchMethodError

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Before everyone jumps on me please read till the end.

I read all of the answers on StackOverflow and they are not working for me.

I trying to add FCM to my app.
I'm getting a run time error

```
03-22 10:29:53.096 15466-15466/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-22 10:29:53.147 15466-15466/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.dr.hyphope-2/lib/arm64
03-22 10:29:53.150 15466-15466/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-22 10:29:53.150 15466-15466/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.dr.hyphope, PID: 15466
                                               java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.example.dr.hyphope-2/base.apk:classes6.dex)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5267)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4862)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4802)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

this is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.example"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}



buildTypes {
    debug{
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'

}
```

as you can see my `firebase-core` and `firebase-messaging` are the same version.
So all the answers on StackOverflow do not work for me.

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: Messaging will include core, by the way, so you didn't need to compile that. But are there any JAR files that are for firebase?

Comment: Is it really multidex necessary in your project? I don't see many dependencies. If not, remove it and test again, if you need it, make sure to have FCM classes in the first dex file.

Comment: no, the jar files are for other libraries.

Comment: @fasteque there are more dependencies i didn't add in the question

Comment: @ilan on which Android version do you see the crash?

Comment: @fasteque 6.0.1

Comment: @ilan I would check if it's a multidex issue or progaurd (unless you have the crash for the debug build as well). In case it's a multidex issue and you cannot disable it, have a look here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep

Comment: @fasteque this happens on debug while running on the phone connected to the cumputer

Comment: @ilan so it's not proguard. I would still check multidex. Are you sure you really need it? If yes, I would suggest you to make a build removing few dependencies and check again FCM. If it's working, it's multidex, so you need to configure it to put FCM classes in the first dex. Wild guess though.

Comment: @fasteque removing mutiDex gave me a transformclasseswithdexfordebug error.
I will try to configure the multidex.

Thasnk

Comment: @ilan if you need it, you can't simply remove the flag, also few dependencies and related code (comment it out).

Comment: @fasteque the error happens on the same function of firebase